# How do I create a batch file that selects a random computer from the list of workgroup computers and runs psexec on one of them?

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a batch file that selects a random computer from the list of LAN computers and runs psexec on one of them?

I want to do something like net view and then parse those results to create a variable that will be selected randomly and then run a psexec on the randomly chosen machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo Computers found:
set n=0
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('net view') do (
    set comp=%%a
    if "!comp:~0,2!" == "\\" (
        echo !n!: !comp!
        set vector[!n!]=!comp!
        set /A n+=1
    )
)

echo Selecting random computer out of %n% computers...

set /A randval=%random% * %n% / 32767
set randcomp=!vector[%randval%]!

echo Selected: %randval%: %randcomp%
```

This script will run `net view` and parse each line to find all computers, counting only the first column and only when it starts with `\\`. It writes all computers into a pseudo-array `vector[...]` and counts the total number in `n`. At the end it generates a random number between 0 and `n` and selects one of the stored computer names based on this number. You can then use `%randcomp%` to your liking.

For example, you could now use `psexec` like this at the end of the batch file:

```
psexec %randcomp% -u Administrator cmd
```

(`-u Administrator cmd` is just an example of course.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for, now as far as the psexec issue, how would I use that %randcomp% variable with psexec?

Comment: I added it to my answer. Basically just use it instead of the computer name, e.g. `psexec %randcomp% cmd` or something. Because I just realized that `psexec` expects the `\\ ` prefix, it means it makes no sense that I remove this prefix in my script. Therefore, you can remove the line `set comp=!comp:\\=!` again.